# Ubuntu 20.10 crashing when attempting to start CS:GO

Tags: games, steam, crash, 20.10

When I'm trying to run Counter-Strike Global Offensive, the native version from Steam, my entire system crashes, and I receive the message with "The system can't recover, please log out". Sometimes, I can successfully start the game without any issues, but usually the system just crashes. I have found a log of the crash in /var/crash but since I am not particularly tech savvy, could someone please find out what the issue is?

Here is a link to the log itself since I seem to be unable to attach it to this post.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ntX8u5nYtyISJStxyKixcRGyGBcQMJ4n/view?usp=sharing

These are my hardware and software specs to help with the issue:
OS: Ubuntu 20.10 x86_64

Kernel: 5.8.0-29-generic

Uptime: 37 mins

Packages: 3004 (dpkg), 12 (flatpak),

Shell: bash 5.0.17

Resolution: 1920x1080

DE: GNOME 3.38.1
Motherboard: ASUS PRIME B450-PLUS

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X (16) @ 3.600G

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

Memory: 10451MiB / 16004MiB

Nvidia Driver: 455.38, using the proprietary tested metapackage

Thank you very much for any help!
The output of the following commands is:
`ls -al /var/crash
total 28792
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie     4096 Nov 22 15:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root         4096 Oct 22 17:17 ..
-rw-r-----  1 andrei whoopsie 29473973 Nov 22 15:19 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash`

free -h
                 `total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi        10Gi       1.3Gi       168Mi       3.7Gi       4.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        40Mi       2.0Gi`

sudo lshw -C memory
`*-firmware

description: BIOS
vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
physical id: 0
version: 2202
date: 07/14/2020
size: 64KiB
capacity: 16MiB
capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
*-memory
description: System Memory
physical id: 27
slot: System board or motherboard
size: 16GiB
*-bank:0
description: [empty]
product: Unknown
vendor: Unknown
physical id: 0
serial: Unknown
slot: DIMM_A1
*-bank:1
description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
product: KHX3200C16D4/8GX
vendor: Kingston
physical id: 1
serial: 1E223000
slot: DIMM_A2
size: 8GiB
width: 64 bits
clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
*-bank:2
description: [empty]
product: Unknown
vendor: Unknown
physical id: 2
serial: Unknown
slot: DIMM_B1
*-bank:3
description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
product: KHX3200C16D4/8GX
vendor: Kingston
physical id: 3
serial: 1FE228F5
slot: DIMM_B2
size: 8GiB
width: 64 bits
clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
*-cache:0
description: L1 cache
physical id: 2a
slot: L1 - Cache
size: 512KiB
capacity: 512KiB
clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
description: L2 cache
physical id: 2b
slot: L2 - Cache
size: 4MiB
capacity: 4MiB
clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
description: L3 cache
physical id: 2c
slot: L3 - Cache
size: 32MiB
capacity: 32MiB
clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
configuration: level=3`

sudo dmidecode

`2202`

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 8 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 14 16:02 .
drwx------ 4 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 22 16:39 ..
drwxrwxr-x 6 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 14 21:59 cpufreq@konkor
drwxrwxr-x 5 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 13 20:04 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 6 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 13 20:28 freon@UshakovVasilii_Github.yahoo.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 14 15:40 gamemode@christian.kellner.me
drwxrwxr-x 3 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 13 20:28 unblank@sun.wxg@gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 andrei andrei 4096 Nov 13 20:04 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`

`ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 22 17:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 17 18:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 22 17:04 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 22 17:04 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 22 17:04 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com`

`cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=ca4c58fb-2d61-4b2f-91d3-4a92bf9ac70a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=FEA5-892E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0`

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to run CS GO?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: I have edited my question to show most of the hardware specs that I can think of. I will add the motherboard too, it's an ASUS PRIME B450-PLUS.

Comment: The output of the first is:
total 28792
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie     4096 Nov 22 15:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root         4096 Oct 22 17:17 ..
-rw-r-----  1 andrei whoopsie 29473973 Nov 22 15:19 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
Of the second is:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi        10Gi       989Mi       256Mi       3.8Gi       4.2Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        40Mi       2.0Gi
And of the third is:
2202

Comment: Please don't place that output into comments. Edit your question and add it there. Thanks!

Comment: Also show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Alright, give me a moment please

Comment: Is your CPU or RAM (XMP) overclocked?

Comment: My CPU is not. My RAM is, in that the manufacturer rated it for 3200 mHZ and I set it as 3200 in the BIOS, with I think DOCP. But it has been like this since before I installed Ubuntu, and it seemed to work just fine with the game even a week ago. Launching CS:GO on my Windows 10 install that I dual-boot with also works without a crash.

Comment: Did this problem occur BEFORE Nov 13?

Comment: I think that I installed Ubuntu on November 13th, but it certainly did not. Even just two days ago I distinctly remember playing CS:GO in Ubuntu without any issues. There was something odd, in that I had more GPU usage showing up in MangoHUD than normally, but I assumed that it was some sort of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

**BIOS**

ASUS PRIME B450-PLUS

As per [this page](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_BIOS/) your BIOS is current at 2202.

**Overclocking**

Your CPU is not overclocked.

Your RAM is overclocked. Please temporarily disable overclocking and set RAM speed back to default. Retest CS:GO. Report back.

**Memory**

AMD Ryzen 7 3700X (16) @ 3.600G

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues.

Determine your processor family with [this document](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_CPU/).

Determine if your memory is supported with [this document](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B450-PLUS/HelpDesk_QVL/).

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Swap**

Your swap may be too small. Monitor `free -h` and note the swap used. If it approaches 2G then you need to enlarge swap.

Check if you're using a /swapfile, or swap partition (UUID=).

```
grep -i swap /etc/fstab
```

If you're using a /swapfile, let's increase your 2G /swapfile to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Nvidia**

There's a newer Nvidia driver available for your GTX 1060. Go to [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/) to get the newer version.

[image]

Comment: Disabling the overclocking and returning the RAM to the original speed still results in the same crash in CS-GO. Using the grep -i swap /etc/fstab command gives me an output that says 0 and none, so I assume that I am not using a swap file. I will run memtest afterwards, but since the two RAM sticks are relatively new, being bought two weeks ago, and since I have no issues with them on my Linux install, I don't know if they are the issue.

I would happily upgrade to the newer driver, but I am not sure how - it does not appear in my Software and Updates Other Drivers section.

Comment: @AshenPaladin Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab`. New vs old memory DIMMs means nothing, especially if we're talking Ryzen processors. Check the supported memory list link I provided. Run `memtest`. To install Nvidia, select the nouveau video driver, then remove current Nvidia driver with `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*`, then install the new version, reselect Nvidia.

Comment: I think that my issue might be related to this one:
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Fossilize/issues/84
Keeping System Monitor in the foreground as I open Counter-Strike, the one thing that really stands out is that I have three or four instances of fossizile replay going and using most of my CPU and Memory.

Comment: @AshenPaladin Hard to say. Somebody does quote a problem with Nvidia Driver 455.38, which is what you're running. Do the items in my answer. As per my last comment, show me `cat /etc/fstab`. swap may still be an issue.

Comment: Added it to my post

Comment: @AshenPaladin Yes, /swapfile is there. I don't know why my grep command didn't find it. Oh well, you can do the swap part of my answer now.

Comment: @AshenPaladin Show me `ls -al /var/crash` one more time.

Comment: @AshenPaladin Status please...

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that I had closed the question. Installing Ubuntu 20.04 instead somehow fixed the issue, the game works perfectly there.

Comment: Trying to reinstall my Nvidia drivers led to a completely back screen and no possibility to access the system itself, so I decided to just start clean again instead, and to stay away from short term releases.